# CakePHP Calendar

Tags: cakephp, calendar

I am new to CakePHP, and would like to create a calendar using this framework.  I am having a difficult time, and am wondering if there is a tutorial or guide on how to create a simple calendar using CakePHP?

Comment: Do you mean a calendar in a database, in the output, or both?

Answer (score 4):

Here are two links: [LINK1](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/silasmontgomery/2011/03/02/cakephp_full_calendar_plugin_2)(calendar helper) and [LINK2](http://duckranger.com/2010/03/fullcalendar-and-cakephp-part-1-set-up/) to a implementation of FullCalendar.
I did not try both of them...

Comment: Link1 (FullCalendar plugin) is fantastic. I use it and it fits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/silasmontgomery/CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin

This is a calendar plugin for cakephp via [fullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download js or css file 
   http://fullcalendar.io/download/
2. Controller code

```
    function feeds(){
        $this->layout   =   'ajax';
        if(isset($this->params->query['start'])){
            $start = $this->params->query['start'];
        }
        if(isset($this->params->query['end'])){
            $end = $this->params->query['end'];
        }   
        $events     =   $this->{$this->modelClass}->find('all',array('conditions' => array('startdate >=' => $start,'enddate  $end)));
        $data = '';
        foreach($events as $res ){          
            $data[] = array(
                    'id' => $res[$this->modelClass]['id'],
                    'title'=> $res[$this->modelClass]['title'],
                    'start'=> Date('Y-m-d H:m',$res[$this->modelClass]['startdate']),
                    'end' => Date('Y-m-d H:m',$res[$this->modelClass]['enddate']),
                    'start_time' => Date('h:ia',$res[$this->modelClass]['startdate']),
                    'end_time' => Date('h:ia',$res[$this->modelClass]['enddate'])                   
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }
```

3. View file 
   Add this in .ctp file

```
    <div class="" id="calendar_div">
```

Js code for view file

```
$('#calendar_div').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
    },      
    defaultView: 'month',
    events: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('action' => 'feeds')); ?>',
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true          
});
```